# render editor in cshtml for a viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following viewmodel :

```
public MyViewModel
{
       prop string p1 {get;set;}
       prop string p2 {get;set;}
}
```

And in my razor view I am trying to implement a form allowing the edition of this model, this is what I've done :

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.p1)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.p2)
}
```

This is working, but it's a little heavy as I must update my razor view with a new line each time I add or remove a property to my viewmodel.
Wouldn't be possible to generate in one line a form allowing the edition of all viewmodel properties. I tried these 2 followings lines, but it rendered nothing :

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.EditorForModel() //or @Html.EditorFor(model => model)
```

Comment: Do you want to make a customized textBox ?

Answer (score 0):

The whole entire point of using editor templates is to customize how things are presented. If all you want to do is call `Html.EditorForModel()`, you can do that straight in the view without needing an editor template at all.

The reason this is not working in particular, is because you basically have a infinite recursion. `Html.EditorForModel()` will utilize the editor template, if there is one, to render the fields for the model. Logically, you can't call that in the actual editor template.

If you want to simplify things, you should work on creating custom editor templates for basic types: String, DateTime, etc. Then you can call something like `Html.EditorForModel()` and it will render fields for all the properties on that model *using the editor templates for those property types*. That way, you get your custom fields, while still not having to manually specify each one. The only reason to create editor templates for complex types like your `MyViewModel` is if you want to do something very specific there. Otherwise, leave it alone.

FWIW, you should *never* include an actual form in an editor template. That's just wrong on oh so many levels, and will create far more problems than you think you're solving.